# Sha256 Digest Mapping to Address

Tags: mapping

Sha256 Message Digests are 32 bytes, however they are typically expressed as a 64 character string. Is it possible to map the string to an address?

Something like

```
mapping (stringToBytes32(bytes32) => address) public digestToAddress;
```

I'd rather not store the string and would like to store the byte32

Answer (score 1):

> would like to store the byte32

Yes, you can do that and just use `bytes32` as the key:

`mapping (bytes32 => address) public digestToAddress;`

The 64 characters are the 32 bytes in hex.